# Which packing constant to use for set_child_packing() in Python

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3, pygi

I want to change a child of a box's padding; so I am using [set_child_packing](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-set-child-packing) on the box holding the child. I can't figure out what to use as the constant for for the pack_type. Using PACK_START from gtk2 won't work as using:
import gtk
causes an error.

What do I use for the pack_type constant?
I am using python with GTK3 on Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks,
Vance

Comment: something like this has been asked a dozen times or so.  constants got moved to logical classes within the Gtk module.  do a dir(Gtk) from a terminal and examine the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Gtk.PackType.START`.

As @aking1012 is mentioning on his comment, these constants got moved around in Gtk 3.

Unfortunately, there is no good documentation on the Gtk 3 Python bindings, so you'll often have to find these out manually until there is.

A way to do it is to open a terminal and use the interactive Python interpreter get a listing of all methods and subclasses of `Gtk`, and then try to guess which one resembles best the constants in the C documentation, as such:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> dir(Gtk)
```

You can also install [ipython](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ipython) and do the same as above, but with **tab completion** instead of using the `dir()` command above:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from gi.repository import Gtk

In [2]: Gtk.(and press TAB here)
```

Comment: Thanks David. I was using IDLE with the dir, but I'll get ipython. The tabbing will be helpful.